# Is status code 404 appropriate when a user isn't authenticated?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

I've been working in web development (mainly as a backend developer) for nearly 10 years, and most services I have worked with return status `401 Unauthorized` when the user is not authenticated. During a recent discussion with a colleague, they suggested that we return status `404 Not Found` when a user isn't authenticated so that we don't even disclose an endpoint even exists at that URL.

I understand where they coming from, but to me it just felt wrong. This way you can't easily tell whether the failure is because the user isn't authenticated, or the URL is incorrect.

I looked at RFC7235, and it states the following:

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
>      not find a current representation for the target resource **or is not
>      willing to disclose that one exists.**

This follows the same argument as my colleague suggested, so should I be returning `404 Not Found` for requests when a user isn't authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a similar statement about `403 Forbidden` status code in [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3):

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a
> forbidden target resource **MAY** instead respond with a status code of
> 404 (Not Found)

So generally it is up to you and your team to decide whether to use `404` or `401` status code.

---

P.S.: some web security apps and tools are analyzing `404` pages to skip similar pages later. And `URL` structure is sometimes get analyzed as well.

So if you have some sensitive data or don't want  to disclose the structure of your project to anybody - `404 Not Found` is a **good idea for security reasons**. And you app/API becomes more difficult to reverse engineer.

The **downside** of this approach is that it's a bit unobvious on the client side - it will be more difficult for your clients to figure out what went wrong when it receives `404 Not Found`.